# ForkJoin observable does not unsubscribe when ngOnDestroy

Tags: angular, reactjs, observable, fork-join, unsubscribe

So my application has a popup window, it has a forkjoin observable that may take a long time to run if the user selects many items. If the user closes the window during the process the application will be in a stand still until the forkjoin is done executing and nothing will be working in my main application. I do unsubscribe the forkjoin by using a subscription but it still runs until it's complete. Here is my code:

```
subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];

ngOnDestroy() {
    // prevent memory leak when component destroyed
    this.subscriptions.forEach(s => s.unsubscribe());

}

//get all my items
getItems() {

    //set item list to blank
    this.itemList = [];
    let observables = [];
    this.loadItems = true;

    //get sections that user selected
    this.subscriptions.push(
    this.organizationService.GetSelectedSections(this.sectionID, this.culture)
        .subscribe(
        (selectedSections: GetSelectedSections[]) => {
            this.selectedSectionsAll = selectedSections;

            //push all selected sections in observables
            for (let section in selectedSections) {
                observables.push(this.organizationService.GetItemsBySection( selectedSections[section].sectionItemID, this.culture));
            }

            // get all items in sections to display
            if (observables.length != 0) {
                this.subscriptions.push(
                Observable.forkJoin(observables)
                    .subscribe(
                    (result: any) => {                          
                        this.itemList = result;
                    },
                    (error: any) => {
                        this.errorMessage = error
                        this.loadItems = false;

                    },
                    () => {
                        this.loadItems = false;
                    }
                  )
                  );                
        }                
        },
        (error: any) => {
            this.errorMessage = error                                
        },
        () => {                
        }
        )
      );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have learned over time that cleaning up your observables correctly are just good practice. Typically, in my ngDestroy I have:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.updateService.clearUpdate(); //this is where I call the next() method 
                                      //on the observable to clear it
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();  //I call this directly on the Subscription object
                                      //To clear obviously unsubscribe
    this.alive = false;               //I use this in the subscribed method in my component
                                      //as a boolean for the rxjs takeWhile() method...
}
```

one of my typical pub/subs

```
this.updateService.getUpdate()
                  .takeWhile(() => this.alive)
                  .subscribe(message => {...impl...}
```

my messaging structure always is external from the component class and is very simple

```
public message = new Subject<any>();
constructor(private zone: NgZone) {
}

sendUpdate(message) {
    this.zone.run(() => {
        this.message.next(message);
    });
}

getUpdate(): Observable<any> {
    this.zone.run(() => {
        this.message.asObservable();
    });
    return this.message.asObservable();
}

clearUpdate() {
    this.zone.run(() => {
        this.message.next();
    });
}
```

I keep things simple as possible. I also use angular's zone() just to make sure the UI is updated in spite of whatever type of circumstance. Hope this helps..